# Tweepy: tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Authorization Required

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am looking forward to extract some data from my profile in Twitter by using the following Tweepy code:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
                                   access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

client.get_tweets(ids=[user_id], tweet_fields=["public_metrics"], expansions=["attachments.media_keys"],
                              media_fields=["public_metrics"])
```

The issue is that for some reason, I get the following error: `tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Authorization Required`, and I know my credentials are valid because I pass tests successfully like the following:

```
lookup_users = api.lookup_users(screen_name=screen_name)
```

The issue here is that I have to authorize the account/app/project to get this data, but I haven't found the documentation related to give those authorizations.

How can I authorize my app to get this info from the account??

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You didn't define "api" anywhere. That seems to be from an older API implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Since the [GET /2/tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets) endpoint `Client.get_tweets` uses allows authentication via bearer token, that's what the method uses by default.

If you want to authorize with user context, you'll have to pass `user_auth` and set it to `True`, as it defaults to `False`, e.g.:

```
client.get_tweets(
    ids=[user_id],
    tweet_fields=["public_metrics"],
    expansions=["attachments.media_keys"],
    media_fields=["public_metrics"],
    user_auth=True
)
```