# Tweepy 401 error on search_recent_tweets <> BUT no 401 when I create_tweet?

Tags: python, authentication, error-handling, tweepy

How come I can create a tweet and like a tweet with no 401 errors? When I try to search for tweets Im getting a 401?

Here's my create_tweet.py file (works fine)

```
import tweepy
import config

# calling a client
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=config.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=config.consumer_secret,
    access_token=config.access_token,
    access_token_secret=config.access_token_secret
)

response = client.create_tweet(text='twitter api testoooor')


print(response)
```

But my search.py file keeps getting a 401 error:

```
import tweepy
import config

# calling a client
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=config.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=config.consumer_secret,
    access_token=config.access_token,
    access_token_secret=config.access_token_secret
)

response = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)

for tweet in response.data:
    print(tweet.id)
```

Really weird that the create_tweet.py isn't getting a 401 error but my search.py file is.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Make sure to pass the `bearer_token` to the client

See below:

```
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=api_key,
                    consumer_secret=api_key_secret,
                    access_token=access_token,
                    access_token_secret=access_secret_key,
                    bearer_token=bearer_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem as you faced.
Maybe this problem has been solved, just to be sure, I describe the solution.

I solved this problem by looking at the answers below.
[Tweepy: tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Authorization Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989983/tweepy-tweepy-errors-unauthorized-401-authorization-required)

please add "user_auth=True" like below

```
client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10,
user_auth=True)
```

At least, I can solved it in this way.